# nosetests --cover-html does not generate html docs

Tags: python, nosetests, code-coverage

I have installed nose for python 2.6 and it works fine but I was trying use the `--cover-html` option to generate a html report. I typed the following command from the command line:

```
nosetests --cover-html
```

It ran the tests but did not generate the html.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 4):

It's old news but the order of the options is important:

```
nosetests --with-coverage --cover-erase --cover-html-dir=C:/temp/res --cover-html test.py
```

Comment: What is the difference between the above command and `nosetests test.py --with-html-out` ?!

Comment: I do not see any with-html-out option is nosetests. I think you are referring to another python package called nose-htmloutput. I don't know about that.

Answer (score 2):

You also need the `--with-coverage` option to enable the coverage plugin in the first place.